# Is $S_{10}$ generated by the group of $6$ cycles?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

> Is $S_{10}$ generated by the subgroup of $6$ cycles?

I'll denote that subgroup by $H$.

We know that by conjugation permutations remains with the same cycle structure, and therefore $H$ is closed to conjugation. It is easy to see from here that $H$ is normal subgroup.

The only normal subgroup of $S_{10}$ is  $A_{10}$, therefore $H$ must be either  $S_{10}$ or $A_{10}$.

How can i determine which one from here?

Are the specific numbers $10,6$ even relevant?

Comment: Hint: what is the sign of a $6$-cycle?

Comment: The set of $6$-cycles do not form a subgroup. You mean is it generated by the *subset* of all $6$-cycles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each $6$-cycle has sign equal to $-1$. Therefore, $H\not\subset A_{10}$.

Comment: Wow, so it's much simpler than I thought, because it just doesn't contain any even permutation, it obviously can't be whole $S_10$.... Correct?

Comment: @ChikChak Yes, that's correct, if the “it” means the set of all $6$-cycles.

Comment: Carlos Santos I mean the group generated by the set of all the $6$-cycles. Is it correct?

Comment: @ChikChak No. For instance, $e\in H$ and it is an even permutation.

Comment: So $H$ must be whole $S_{10}$, right? As it is normal, and isn't $A_{10}$ because it contains also odd permutations.

Comment: @ChikChak Yes, that's it.